# need to compress QImage to send it via IP

Tags: qt, qimage

i'm programming an application (in C++/Qt Designer 4.6 and using some librairies like `ffmpeg` and `v4l2`) which capture from webcam and i want to send the captured `QImage` via IP, so i send it into a `QTcpSocket` and i succed in receiving it in my server application but the problem it's too slow, crearly because the `QImage` isn't compressed so i'm not getting the wanted result which is live video streaming via IP, my question is how can i compress the `QImage`? I think in converting it to the `YUV` format but i can't realize it, this is some lines from my code to send the available `QImage`:

```
QImage image;
QByteArray ba;
QBuffer buffer(&ba);
image.save(&buffer, "PNG");
imsocket->write(ba);
```

Comment: If high throughput is important don't compress or use very fast compressors like LZ4. And low latency jpeg transcoder is "turbojpeg".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be better off sending an MPEG compressed video stream instead of compressing each frame as QImage and sending it over network.

MPEG compressed video streams use a technique which uses a full scale image for first frame and then only records changed pixels for each proceeding frame thus providing maximum compression as well as smooth video playback over the network.

On the client end, you will playback by getting frames generated by the library from the compressed MPEG stream.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem as the above, my code looked like this:

```
QBuffer buffer;
buffer.open(QIOdevice::WriteOnly);
QDataStream stream(&buffer);
stream << image;
```

Using QElapsedTimer I found that encoding the image took more than 500 msec for a 1024x768 sized image. Using valgrind I found that the time was spend in *png_write_image* which was called from *QImageWriter::write(QImage)*

Changing the code to encode as a JPG instead, made the code execute in only 5ms for the same image. The resulting code looked like this:

```
QBuffer buffer;
buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
image.save(&buffer,"JPEG");
```

Unfortunately I found no way to tell QDataStream to encode images in JPG rather than PNG, so the decoding side obviously needed to be adapted to decode the image like:

```
image.load(&buffer, "JPEG");
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you send off the image, you can [compress](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/faq/answer/how_to_compress_data_with_qt) the byte array and then de-compress it on the server. This should provide a nice boost for you.

```
QByteArray arr, cArr;
cArr = qCompress(arr);
```

Comment: thnks JadziaMD i tried this one, it looks better but the application works so slowly i think it consumes much cpu, i still working on...

Comment: You could try reducing the size of the image & the level of compression used to reduce the CPU load.

Answer (score 0):

You should adhere to the first rule of optimization: Don't optimize when you have not measured where your application spends its time. I asume you are just guessing which part pf your application is slow.